# Serve very basic WMS data to a GIS system from my PHP server

Tags: layers, php, geocortex

Apologies for the basic nature of this question - I hadn't heard of GIS until this morning! I have a PHP server with some basic data for geographic points in a MySQL database - each one has a latitude, longitude, an image and some text. A customer asked me if I could feed this as a layer into their GIS system (based on Geocortex), and I mistakenly said that I was sure it would be easy. Uh-huh.

After much research and experimentation, I'm at a loss as to what my general approach to this problem should be - should I install a GIS system and somehow copy my data there? Should I roll my own PHP to respond to WMS requests and return the specific layers I need? And how on earth do I go from my data set to the drawing layer that Geocortex seems to need?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Geocortex Site, then the easy way to consume your data is by using a Workflow to make the web request from the Geocortex Essentials server, which can then create a new Graphics Layer and add it to their map.

If you don't, then making a WMS server is one option.  However, it would be simpler to generate a [GeoRSS feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoRSS) of your points instead, since GeoRSS only requires that you implement a single handler and not multiple types of requests.

A GeoRSS feed can be added to a Geocortex Site directly.  If they have trouble adding the feed, have them post to the Geocortex support forum and we'll help from there.